# Is there work on oneself or service of Hashem which is specific to older age, say over 70?

Tags: mussar-ethics, age

Do the sources specify the sort of work on oneself or service of Hashem which is specific to older age, say over 70?

I might have thought that the differences that are brought on by age as expressed in [Avos 5 (21)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%90#.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.A9.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.99.D7.9D)

> הוא היה אומר, בן חמש שנים למקרא, בן עשר למשנה, בן שלש עשרה למצות, בן
>   חמש עשרה לתלמוד, בן שמונה עשרה לחפה, בן עשרים לרדוף, בן שלשים לכח, בן
>   ארבעים לבינה, בן חמשים לעצה, בן ששים לזקנה, בן שבעים לשיבה, בן שמונים
>   לגבורה, בן תשעים לשוח, בן מאה כאלו מת ועבר ובטל מן העולם.‏

might have implications, eg   בן שמונים לגבורה might imply that one is given or needs special strength from 80 years and בן מאה כאלו מת ועבר ובטל מן העולם could imply that there is nothing further to worry about when one reaches 100 years old.

To be clear, I am not seeking a commentary on this mishnah but rather an answer to the general question.

Comment: They say (whoever 'they' are) that among the prerequisites to learn Zohar is being 40 years old. That's sort of the opposite of what you're asking, though, it's not a requirement brought upon by age, rather a restriction removed by age.

Comment: Don't forget the other earlier Mishnah - אל תאמין בעצמך עד יום מותך. As long as you're alive you have what to work on.

Comment: @DonielF Yes. But are there any special areas to concentrate on?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Are there any special areas to concentrate on for 30-year-olds? I'd say everyone has their own unique path to work on, and there is no single answer to these sorts of questions.